# How can I change my character's Dragon Age: Origins backstory in Dragon Age 2 without having to replay lots of the game?

Tags: dragon-age-origins, dragon-age-2

I'm at the last chapter of Dragon Age 2 when I read somewhere online that my last choice for the *Witch Hunt* DLC didn't carry over to DA 2 if I wasn't patched. So I tried recreating my save and starting a new game, but halfway through the first chapter I realized that going through ALL those repetitive dungeons for 3 chapters again might not be worth it.

I have a gut feeling that the backstory for my DA 2 character and its influences from DA:O is just stored in the character file. Is there a way for me to change one particular event from my DA:O backstory (particularly, the part where I leave with Morrigan through the mirror) so that I won't have to go through the whole game again?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this in the console, with the command:

```
runscript zz_pre_debug
```

The description according to the [Dragon age wiki](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Console_%28Origins%29) is:

> Starts the Prelude Debug Helper Script which allows modification of plot states and teleporting.

You access the console with the back tick character (`), although you can change it by doing [the following:](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Console_%28Origins%29)

> Open the file "\BioWare\Dragon Age\Settings\KeyBindings.ini" in your My Documents folder. Find the line that says "OpenConsole_0". You can change the value after the equals sign (=) to the key or key combination you want to use for opening the console after running the game. E.g.: change it to "Keyboard::Button_Tilde" to open the console by pressing the ~ button in the top left corner of your keyboard.

Unfortunately, I am unable to find any information on how to use the script itself once you run it, and since I don't have the game on PC I can't test it out myself. Either way, I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried it. It lets me view the backstory but not change it. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use zz_epi_debug to quickly change your epilogue. However, some of the detailed choices won't be available (you can choose if you allies with mages or templars, but not if Connor lives or dies, e.g.).

Also, if you want some fine tuning, there's lots of commands to set plot flags:

zz_cir_debug (Broken circle quest)

zz_lot_debug (Lothering)
...

and a lot more. You can check a full list [here](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Console_%28Origins%29)